# github account SSH key not working

Tags: github, ssh, public-key

I have a `id_keynamex`associated with my github account which was added from my local `~/.ssh/` to `https://github.com/settings/keys`. This key has no password and is tied to my account as a whole.

I have tracked my project to a repository in my account: `origin    git@github.com:MyUser/projectX.git`, however whenever I try to commit `git push origin master` I am requested to type a password for another key in my ssh folder:

`Enter passphrase for key '/Users/myUser/.ssh/id_rsa':`

If I already have a generic key for my entire github account, why is git asking me to refer to `/Users/myUser/.ssh/id_rsa`  instead of `/Users/myUser/.ssh/id_keynamex`?

EDITED:

I have added the following to the .ssh/config file:

```
Host github.com
    User           git
    Hostname github.com
    IdentityFile   ~/.ssh/id_keynamex

Host github.com
  Hostname ssh.github.com
  IdentityFile   ~/.ssh/id_keynamex
  Port 443
```

However, I am still getting the following issue:

```
ssh_exchange_identification: Connection closed by remote host
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

Comment: it may help to mention what OS you're using

Comment: Does git know which key to use? If you've not specified it anywhere, it'll default to the standard `id_rsa`. I would add `github.com` to `.ssh/config` file and specify the key there.

Comment: I have amended my question above. I am still having issues. Do I need to add a separate ssh key for the project?

Answer (score 0):

I removed the following from my config file:

```
Host github.com
  Hostname ssh.github.com
  IdentityFile   ~/.ssh/id_keynamex
  Port 443
```

So that I only have one instance of this host and now it appears to work.